# gravar imagens no banco postgresql com php

Tags: php, postgresql

Pretendo fazer upload de imagens através do browser para um banco postgresql usando php.
Testei com lo_import mas dá-me um erro indicando que tem de ser através de superuser no server side.
Alguma sugestão?

A minha tabela:

```
create table tabela as (id serial unique, imagem oid)
```

Comment: Experimenta com o `lo_import` do cliente, não do servidor. Nesse caso, a implementação do PHP é a [`pg_lo_import`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-lo-import.php). As [functions de large object do servidor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-funcs.html) PostgreSQL, quando manipulam arquivos no filesystem, tendem a rodar com as permissões do usuário de SO do próprio Postgres, o que cria uma série de probleminhas de permissionamento de filesystem e a necessidade do PHP se conectar como superuser, o q não é uma boa.

Comment: tem algum exemplo? pesquisei e os exemplos que encontrei não resultaram de forma alguma, ficou confuso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito bater com a cabeça e ver exemplos pouco claros, maior parte cópias do manual que também não são bem claros, consegui carregar a imagem do cliente para o banco no servidor sem ter o problema do superuser no postgresql.

Primeiro, envie a imagem para uma pasta temporária no servidor, depois é pegar na imagem na pasta local e carregar no banco.
Código completo:

*postgresql*

```
create table testeimg as (id serial unique, imagem oid)
```

*form*

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">         
<input type="file" name="imagem">            
<button formaction="upload.php">UPLOAD</button>                
</form>
```

*upload.php*

```
/* postgresql conexão */
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=teste user=usuario password=pass") or die('Não foi possível conectar: ' . pg_last_error()); 

/* recebe a imagem do formulário, define a pasta de destino, renomeia o arquivo para nome único e envia para a pasta indicada */
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '_tmp/'); 
$img = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img); 
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

/* pega a imagem na pasta tmp e grava a imagem no banco */
pg_query($dbconn, "begin");
$oid = pg_lo_import($dbconn, '_tmp/'.$data . '.jpg');
$sql1 = "insert into testeimg (img) values('$oid')";
$res1 = pg_query($dbconn,$sql1) or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
pg_query($dbconn, "commit");

/* elimina a imagem temporária */
unlink(UPLOAD_DIR . $idcliente . '.jpg');
```